# Reload whole page in 'lightning' using java script

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning-aura-components

I have added 'VF Page' in lightning, I just want to refresh the whole page using javascript when event raised in VF page.
I have used windw.location.reload().
But its not working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm) to force all data to reload, but the page itself still will not reload. This is because Lightning is meant to be a Single Page Application (SPA). Example code from the documentation is as follows:

```
refresh : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = cmp.get('c.myController');
    action.setCallback(cmp,
        function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            } else {
                 //do something
            }
        }
    );
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: I just checked that "window.location.href" and "window.location.reload" return valid values inside a JS controller and when I call window.location.reload(true), the entire page gets refreshed. Not sure why the page will not reload as per your answer. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @the_phantom force:refreshView is the recommended approach to "reload" Lightning. This eliminates the 1-3 second loading time. If you want to use location.reload, you can, but I'd advise against it unless you have no other way.